# How to remove count when deselected button from array using javaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i'm selecting button then value come on the `console.log` it is working fine using array. I also want to remove value from console when deselect button.

```js
var totalWishlist = [];

$('.btn').click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass('active');
  totalWishlist.push($(this).data('pid'));
  console.log(totalWishlist.join(', '));
});
```

```css
.btn{background:gray; color:#fff; padding:10px; border-radius:15px; margin-bottom:10px; display:inline-block;}
.active{background:red; color:#fff; padding:10px; border-radius:15px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn" data-pid="1">btton 1</div>
<div class="btn" data-pid="2">btton 2</div>
<div class="btn" data-pid="3">btton 3</div>
<div class="btn" data-pid="4">btton 4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to just build the array within each event handler instead of maintaining it manually when a new element is clicked/one is removed. To do that you can use `map()` like this:

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  
  var totalWishlist = $('.btn.active').map(function() {
    return $(this).data('pid');
  }).get();
  console.log(totalWishlist.join(', '));
});
```

```css
.btn {
  background: gray;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.active {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn" data-pid="1">btton 1</div>
<div class="btn" data-pid="2">btton 2</div>
<div class="btn" data-pid="3">btton 3</div>
<div class="btn" data-pid="4">btton 4</div>
```

Comment: @thanks Rory McCrossan, its working fine that i want.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the class existence so that you can add/remove the item:

```js
var totalWishlist = [];

$('.btn').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  if($(this).hasClass('active'))
    totalWishlist.push($(this).data('pid'));
  else
    totalWishlist = totalWishlist.filter(i => i!= $(this).data('pid'));
  console.log(totalWishlist.join(', '));
});
```

```css
.btn{background:gray; color:#fff; padding:10px; border-radius:15px; margin-bottom:10px; display:inline-block;}
.active{background:red; color:#fff; padding:10px; border-radius:15px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn" data-pid="1">btton 1</div>
<div class="btn" data-pid="2">btton 2</div>
<div class="btn" data-pid="3">btton 3</div>
<div class="btn" data-pid="4">btton 4</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work - `pop()` only removes the last element of the array, not the one which is clicked

Comment: @RohitVerma, you are most welcome...also please notice the update using `filter()`:)